# BASH Problemas para guardar pipe awk en variable y luego ejecutarla llamando a la variable

Tags: bash, variables, awk

Buenas tardes para todos,

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente con BASH:

Si ejecuto el siguiente codigo:

```bash
var_echo="echo "
var_text="uno dos tres" 
var_pipe=" | awk '{print \\$2}' "

#Aqui ejecuto todas las variables juntas

EJECUTAR=$($var_echo $var_text $var_pipe )

#muestro el valor
echo "$EJECUTAR"
```

resultado:

```
uno dos tres | awk '{print $2}'
```

Solo me muestra los caracteres almacenados en las variables de corrido sin el "echo", Pero si lo ejecuta de la siguiente manera si funciona

```bash
var_echo="echo "
var_text="uno dos tres"
EJECUTAR=$($var_echo $var_text | awk '{print $2}' )
echo "$EJECUTAR"
```

Resultado:

```
dos
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que el pipe con awk me funcione desde la variable, no doy con el error?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes pasarlo como una cadena al comando *bash*. Por ejemplo:

```bash
var_echo="echo "
var_text="uno dos tres" 
var_pipe=" | awk '{print \$2}'"

#Aqui ejecuto todas las variables juntas

EJECUTAR="$(bash -c "$var_echo $var_text $var_pipe")"

#muestro el valor
echo "$EJECUTAR"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Esto me sirve. gracias por el gran aporte.
un saludo grande.